# Creating a new React Project on VS Code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, hadoop-yarn

i'm trying to create a new React project in VS Code but i keep getting this error..I tried Re-installing npm and Node.js and Yarn and clearing cache also I tried changing the folder directory..any one has a clue how to solve this issue?

I was trying to create a new React project and I was expecting it to load normally and create a new project.

Comment: which error you got?

Comment: Add which error you are getting and which command you are running.